# Update the Chartjs push data with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js, reload

This is the code that I have created to render chart with **Chart.js** library:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
            url : "data.php",
            type : "JSON",
            success : function(data){

                var lung = data.length;         

                console.log(data);

                var timestamp_utc = [];
                var temperature = [];


                for(var i in data) {
                    timestamp_utc.push(data[i].timestamp_utc);
                    temperature.push(data[i].temperature);


                }


                var config_temp = {
                    labels: timestamp_utc.slice(lung-10, lung),
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "temperature",
                            fill: false,
                            lineTension: 0.1,
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 169, 252, 0.75)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(0, 169, 252, 1)",
                            pointRadius: "5",
                            pointColor: "rgba(0, 169, 252, 1)",
                            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 169, 252, 1)",
                            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0, 169, 252, 1)",
                            data: temperature.slice(lung-10, lung)
                        }]
                };


                var ctx_temp = $("#mycanvas");

                var LineGraph_temp = new Chart(ctx_temp, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: config_temp
                });



    },

            error : function(data) {

            }
        });


    });
```

I want to update graph every 15 minutes.
how can I do that?

Comment: setInterval(function(){// put your ajax call in there}, 900000);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` method to execute the code which renders the chart with updated data.

```
var pollInterval = 15000;  //change this value as needed
function renderChart() {
   // put your existing code to render the chart here
}

$(function () {
     window.setInterval(renderChart, pollInterval);
});
```

Comment: Your solution works, but it's not what I wanted ...


I want you to upload the data took place with this style:

http://jsbin.com/yitep/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes but how?
I thought about putting in a variable of the ajax response data.
it's correct?